# Not able to inflate a layout in android

Tags: android

mainactivity.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="#ff0"
    android:id="@+id/myframe"
    >


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:background="#00f"
        />
</FrameLayout>
```

sublayout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#f0f"
    >

</TextView>
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.sublayout, null);
        FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.myframe);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        frameLayout.addView(view);
    }


}
```

I got the error as "A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
    java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called"

Comment: can you post full stacktrace

Comment: FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.myframe);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) you are finding before setting view contents?

Comment: What is your purpose of inflating?

Comment: 08-28 16:07:32.177    3083-3092/? E/StrictMode﹕ A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
    java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called
            at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
            at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor.<init>(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:180)
            at android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(ParcelFileDescriptor.java:916)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is you tried to access the view before setting the content view try this..

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.myframe);
 LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();
 View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.sublayout, null);
 frameLayout.addView(view);
 }
```

Comment: itried to put setcontentView() at the end. but still the same error

Comment: @BrightVarghese put setContentView on below oncreate method(i.e below super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

Comment: is it must that setContentView() should be added in the code? I tried without this method also. but the same error

Comment: setContentView has nothing to do with your code. You need it called just after you call super.onCreate() to set the view that will be later used to do stuff with findViewById()

Comment: I tried according to ur suggestion. Its working. Thank u very much

Comment: Yeah. I got the result.

Comment: now i want to include few more lines in the same code. but i got the same error. @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();

        FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.myframe);
       LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.mylinear);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.sublayout, linearLayout);
        frameLayout.addView(view);

    }